# Swift WKWebView

Tags: ntlm, wkwebview

how to handle NTLM authentication using WKWebView, the aim is to load a secured URL with credentials  (Sharepoint Hosted application) similarly I wanted to add a key value pair to the http request
any code sample using swift2.0 that handles my case will be appreciated .

Comment: waiting for an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the documentation and I have found the solutions below is the equivalent of the method shouldSatratLoading etc..

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    print("  decidePolicyForNavigationAction.......")
    let headerArr = navigationAction.request.allHTTPHeaderFields?.keys.array
    let headerIsPresent =  headerArr?.contains(APP_HEADER_ID)

    if headerIsPresent! {
         decisionHandler(.Allow)
    }else{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                let newRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = navigationAction.request as! NSMutableURLRequest
                // set new header
                newRequest.addValue(APP_HEADER_VALUE, forHTTPHeaderField:APP_HEADER_ID)

                // reload the request
                webView.loadRequest(newRequest)
            })
        })
      decisionHandler(.Cancel)
    }
}
```

If anyone needs more info please let me know